# Древо и дерево - разве это одно и то же?

Tags: значение-слов

"Древо" и "дерево" — существует ли разница?

Comment: примерно 300 лет назад слова "дерево" письменно не существовало,  также как тройка -> троица, отпуск -> отпуст, зеркало->зерцало

Comment: Понятия "древо" и "дерево" различали испокон веков. Сейчас ни один словарь не скажет вам о разнице этих понятий. Почему?

Comment: Не могли бы Вы, пожалуйста, привести любой письменный источник ранее 18 века содержащий любое из следующих слов: голод, солод, молод, колода, холод, болото, дерево, корова, ворон, воробей, борода

Comment: Извините, уважаемый, поясните связь вашего запроса с "древо" и "дерево"?

Comment: Вы указали "испокон веков", прошу письменный источник ранее 18 века со словом "дерево"

Comment: Я просил указать связь вашего вопроса с моим вопросом, а вы запрашиваете с меня выкладки других деятелей по слову "дерево".  Вы понимаете, что просите?

Comment: Я не отвечаю за других деятелей. Мне словари не авторитет.

Answer (score 3):

Словари нам в помощь. Потому что если не читать словарей, собственной интуицией невозможно будет объять все тонкости русского языка. Тем более, что неподготовленного носителя языка эта интуиция зачастую обманывает.

> ДРЕВО, -а; мн. древеса, -вес, -ам; ср. Трад.-поэт. 1. =Дерево (1 зн.).
>   2. чего или с опр. Книжн. Графическое или символическое изображение чего-л., представляемого в виде дерева. Д. жизни (высок.; сама жизнь,
>   существование). Д. познания (высок.; само познание добра и зла, от
>   библейского сказания об Адаме и Еве, вкусивших в раю запретный плод и
>   познавших тайну продолжения жизни). Родословное, генеалогическое д.
>   (изображение истории рода таким способом).

Как видим, нет никакой пометки, что второе значение устарело, но оно "книжное". Другое дело, что это слово в таком значении традиционно не используется в математике и близлежащих областях. Так что область применения слов "дерево" и "древо" в этом значении действительно несколько отличается стилистически (см. ниже).

> ДЕРЕВО, -а; мн. деревья, -вьев и (устар.) дерева, -рев; ср. 1.
>   Многолетнее растение с твёрдым стволом и ветвями, образующими крону.
>   Хвойные деревья. Фруктовые деревья. Высокое раскидистое старое д.
>   Больное, засохшее д. Посадить, вырастить д. Срубить, спилить д. Лежать
>   под деревом. Упасть с дерева. Д. сбросило листву. 2. только ед.
>   Древесный материал, идущий на изделия, постройки; древесина. Резьба по
>   дереву. Игрушки из дерева. Мебель красного дерева. Постучи по дереву
>   (шутл.; по суеверным представлениям: чтобы не сглазить что-л., нужно
>   постучать по чему-л. деревянному). 3. Матем. Модель структуры данных,
>   напоминающая очертанием древесную крону. Д. является связным графом,
>   не содержащим циклы. // Схематическое изображение, воспроизводящее
>   такую структуру данных. Родословное, генеалогическое д. (схема
>   родственных связей в виде древовидной структуры).

Comment: Подожду что другие скажут. Через месяц дам понятные описания понятий и сравните их со словарями.

Answer (score 0):

Да, в русском языке "древо" и "дерево" являются практически полными синонимами.

*"Практически" потому что "древо жизни" и "дерево жизни" вряд ли взаимозаменямы, других таких примеров придумать не получается.*

Comment: А как же: глас - голос; плен - полон; враг - ворог; град - город; враг -ворог и д.р. вон сколько примеров

Comment: Примеров чего? Какое отношение все эти слова имеют к вопросу про древо-дерево?

Comment: Вряд ли взаимозаменяемы: глас - голос; плен - полон; враг - ворог; град - город; враг -ворог и д.р. вон сколько примеров.

Comment: Какое отношение все эти слова имеют к словам "древо" и "дерево"?

Comment: Думаю "дерево жизни" более употребимо, чем "древо". Другое дело, что дерево это может быть не только растение, но и материал, а также модель структуры данных. Вот там "древо" будет звучать натянуто архаично :)

Comment: Сибиряк, имеют прямое отношение, потому что: 1) так называемая 'проглоченная буква' вводит в заблуждение знатоков и воспринимается ими как тождественное слово, но устаревшее, но ведь это не так! 2) словари умалчивают о разнице.

Comment: grizzly, в правильном направлении думаете... "структуры данных".

Comment: Вопрос был про "древо" и "дерево". Я не отвечаю за другие слова, мне они не авторитет.

Comment: А ещё язык не поворачивается сказать "растекаться мыслью по дереву" :)

Comment: @grizzly Мой язык не поворачивается сказать "дерево жизни", а "мыслью по дереву" - вполне :)

Comment: grizzly, это из-за непонимания

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/26939)

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Вопрос: одно и то же? Ответ: да. Что тогда является ответом на вопрос?

Comment: Древо и дерево - одно и то же слово, различающиеся стилистически, сферой употребления. А вовсе не синонимы.

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova это означает, что ответ неверный, плохой, и т.п.  Но никак не "не является ответом на вопрос".  Если бы я написал "посмотрите в словаре", или что-нибудь уточнял, как предлагает описание этой причины закрытия, то это было бы "не является ответом на вопрос". А в текущем виде самый обычный ответ на вопрос.